# ratingbar can not show current numStars

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have a RatingBar and use the method setNumStars(final int numStars).
 in XML the code is like this :

```
 <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
                style="@style/CMYMyRatingBars"
                android:isIndicator="true"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="5"
                />
```

then there is a problem . When the numStars is 0. My RatingBar will show 5 stars.

Comment: Did u set setOnRatingBarChangeListener on your rating bar?

Comment: No. i don't think it's the key of the problem.

Comment: show your `CMYMyRatingBars`

Comment: <style name="CMYMyRatingBars" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

Comment: your ratingbar work with another rate (ex: 2 , 2.5 ...) ???

Comment: for test case add `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

Comment: add `android:max="5"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya then also not work

Comment: what does it mean when the numstars is 0?

Comment: it means setNumStars(0) ;

Comment: @BurakCakir for if you want 5 star then you are write `numStars = 5` now write `numStars = 0` it also display 5 star , I think now you understand the problem

Comment: @Harshad that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private RatingBar ratingBar;
private float ratingValue;

ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);

ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) { 

                ratingValue = rating;

            }
        });

ratingBar.getRating();



<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
    style="@style/CMYMyRatingBars"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="0"
    android:rating="4"
     />
```

Because you have given the rating 5 that is why it is showing 5 rating when you are giving 0 numStars. I have executed this code and code is working fine.You have to see zero rating then implement this code.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rating_bar"
    style="@style/CMYMyRatingBars"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="0"
    android:rating="0"
     />
```

styles

```
<style name="CMYMyRatingBars" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

ratingbar.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_empty"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_empty"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_filled"/>
```

ratingbar_filled.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staron"/>
```

ratingbar_empty.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff" android:state_selected="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_staroff"/>
```

Comment: Why to add the ChangeListener ?  the ratingBar will not change . i have a int value calls numStars. and i want to set the num. But when the num is 0 . ratingBar show 5 stars.